# Set field values in SOLR

Tags: solr, dih

Is it possible to set a field's value in SOLR's DIH file?
I would like not to retrieve the database field's value and I want to have a calculated value instead.

Answer (score 0):

calculated based on what? if it is other db column values it is easy, but it is more a sql than Solr question:

```
SELECT a,b, (a+b) AS calculated FROM thetable
```